# how do I reassign new values to python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to convert prices like " €565K " to integers and I know that pandas dataframes require reassigning, so I wrote the code like this :

```
def to_int(cols):
    for column in cols:
        column = column.astype(str)
        for i in range(len(column)):
            if column[i][-1] == 'M':
                column[i] = float(column[i][1:-1])*1000000
            elif column[i][-1] == 'K':
                column[i] = float(column[i][1:-1])*1000
```

but it doesn't reassign the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `apply`

```
def to_int(x):
    if x[-1] == 'M':
        return float(x[1:-1])*1000000
    elif x[-1] == 'K':
        return float(x[1:-1])*1000
df['col_with_price'] = df['col_with_price'].apply(to_int)
print(df)
```